# How combine android SimpleCursorAdapter result?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, simplecursoradapter

I'm trying to populate *sqlite* records into a *listview*.
In my table, I'm splitting an address into columns e.g **Street, Postcode, City & State**.
I'm using *SimpleCursorAdapter* to load results into views like in the code below:
Here is my ListActivity.java

```
private DBManager dbManager;
private ListView listView;
private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
DbHelper myDb;

final String[] from = new String[] {
        DbHelper.COL_NAME,
        DbHelper.COL_STREET,
        DbHelper.COL_POSTCODE,
        DbHelper.COL_CITY,
        DbHelper.COL_STATE };


final int[] to = new int[] { R.id.name, R.id.address };


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_emp_list);

    dbManager = new DBManager(this);
    myDb = new DbHelper(this);
    dbManager.open();
    Cursor cursor = dbManager.fetch();

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    listView.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.empty));
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_view_record, cursor, from, to, 0);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here is my view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/id"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/address"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/nama"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/id"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:visibility="visible" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

My problem is, how to combine **STREET, POSTCODE, CITY, STATE** and put them into **R.id.address**?
Using the above method, i have to create a textview for each column, otherwise, it will error.

Comment: Just want  add the text?

Comment: yes. all 4 column into single textview

Answer (score 0):

Make the following changes:

1. In your layout xml change

   ```
   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/address"
       android:text="@string/format_address"
       ......
       />
   ```
2. In your strings.xm add the following:

   ```
   <string name="format_address">%1$s, %2$s, %3$s, %4$s</string>
   ```
3. In your source code add the following:

   ```
   Resources res = getResources();
   String text = String.format(res.getString(R.string.format_address), STREET_VALUE, POSTCODE_VALUE, CITY_VALUE, STATE_VALUE);
   ```

**NOTE** STREET_VALUE, POSTCODE_VALUE, CITY_VALUE, STATE_VALUE replace with actual values or String ref.

Comment: nope. I think i have to edit the question for more information.